# verifying a form with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Here is the code for the form:

```
<form>
    <h1>Michael</h1>
    <ul style="list-style-type: none;">
        <li>Name:
            <input type="text" id="username" size="30" maxlength="40">
        </li>
        <li>&nbsp;</li>
        <li>Password:
            <input type="password" id="password" size="30" maxlength="40">
        </li>
        <li>
            <li>&nbsp;</li>
            <input type="button" id="submit" value="Submit" onclick="check()">
        </li>
        <li>&nbsp;</li>
    </ul>
</form>
```

and here is the validating code:

```
function check() {
    if (document.getElementById("username").value = "username") {
        if (document.getElementById("password").value = "password") {
            window.location.href = "wreck.html";
        }
    }
    else {
        document.location.reload(true);
    }
}
```

i would like to validate the form and if the username and password is correct, then go to a specific page. Any suggestions?

Comment: what problem you are facing in current code?

Comment: Can you explain what went wrong?

Comment: Give some insight on your stack. What server-side tech are you using? We might be able to point you in a better direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, if you notice you are using the assignment **=** operator in your if statement instead of equality **===** operator.

it should be

```
if (document.getElementById("username").value === "username") {
    if (document.getElementById("password").value === "password") {
        window.location.href = "wreck.html";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should reconsider your strategy.

The javascript code for your `check()` function will be downloaded by and viewable by every visitor.

That means your current approach would:

1. Publicly expose your visitor's usernames and passwords.
2. Allow any visitor to redirect themselves to anything behind your login form.

**While basic validations (verifying content was entered or is in a valid format) can be performed client-side...AUTHENTICATION of user credentials should *ALWAYS* be performed on server-side.**

If you want to do this through a client-side function instead of posting the form normally...

1. The function should submit the form input to the server via an ajax call.
2. The server-side function should perform validation and response should include the desired redirect location.

Comment: Validation could also be performed on client-side. (good for immediate feedback)

Comment: Your answer makes more sense now. (My bad, misunderstood what you meant before)

Answer (score 0):

First, we do all the heavy lifting using vanilla JS. After that, we use some CSS to give it some proper styling and the validation flags, and finally, we do our basic HTML markup. Don't forget to match all the ids. Here I did an email validation, but the same principles can be applied with your username, passwords, etc ... simply by checking the lengths, types, etc ... using `if statements`.  Run the code snippet and see if this works for you. I truly hope it does :)

```js
// There are fewer ways to pick a DOM node with legacy browsers
var form  = document.getElementsByTagName('form')[0];
var email = document.getElementById('mail');

 document.getElementById("myForm").onsubmit = function() {
     alert(document.getElementById("mail").value);
 }

// The following is a trick to reach the next sibling Element node in the DOM
// This is dangerous because you can easily build an infinite loop.
// In modern browsers, you should prefer using element.nextElementSibling
var error = email;
while ((error = error.nextSibling).nodeType != 1);

// As per the HTML5 Specification
var emailRegExp = /^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$/;

// Many legacy browsers do not support the addEventListener method.
// Here is a simple way to handle this; it's far from the only one.
function addEvent(element, event, callback) {
  var previousEventCallBack = element["on"+event];
  element["on"+event] = function (e) {
    var output = callback(e);

    // A callback that returns `false` stops the callback chain
    // and interrupts the execution of the event callback.
    if (output === false) return false;

    if (typeof previousEventCallBack === 'function') {
      output = previousEventCallBack(e);
      if(output === false) return false;
    }
  }
};

// Now we can rebuild our validation constraint
// Because we do not rely on CSS pseudo-class, we have to 
// explicitly set the valid/invalid class on our email field
addEvent(window, "load", function () {
  // Here, we test if the field is empty (remember, the field is not required)
  // If it is not, we check if its content is a well-formed e-mail address.
  var test = email.value.length === 0 || emailRegExp.test(email.value);

  email.className = test ? "valid" : "invalid";
});

// This defines what happens when the user types in the field
addEvent(email, "input", function () {
  var test = email.value.length === 0 || emailRegExp.test(email.value);
  if (test) {
    email.className = "valid";
    error.innerHTML = "";
    error.className = "error";
  } else {
    email.className = "invalid";
  }
});

// This defines what happens when the user tries to submit the data
addEvent(form, "submit", function () {
  var test = email.value.length === 0 || emailRegExp.test(email.value);

  if (!test) {
    email.className = "invalid";
    error.innerHTML = "I expect an e-mail, darling!";
    error.className = "error active";

    // Some legacy browsers do not support the event.preventDefault() method
    return false;
  } else {
    email.className = "valid";
    error.innerHTML = "";
    error.className = "error";
  }
});
```

```css
/* This is just to make the example nicer */
body {
  font: 1em sans-serif;
  padding: 0;
  margin : 0;
}

form {
  max-width: 200px;
}

p * {
  display: block;
}

input.mail {
  -webkit-appearance: none;

  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  margin: 0;

  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: 90%;

  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* This is our style for the invalid fields */
input.invalid{
  border-color: #900;
  background-color: #FDD;
}

input:focus.invalid {
  outline: none;
}

/* This is the style of our error messages */
.error {
  width  : 100%;
  padding: 0;
 
  font-size: 80%;
  color: white;
  background-color: #900;
  border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
 
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.error.active {
  padding: 0.3em;
}
```

```html
<form id="myForm">
  <p>
    <label for="mail">
        <span>Please enter an valid email address:</span>
        <input type="text" class="mail" id="mail" name="mail">
        <span class="error" aria-live="polite"></span>
    </label>
  <p>
  <!-- Some legacy browsers need to have the `type` attribute
       explicitly set to `submit` on the `button`element -->
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```